# VM Loading Windows 8.1 dual-boot partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, virtualization

I just decided to try out Ubuntu (I'm new to Linux, so bear with me please).

I had Windows 8 installed and want/need to keep it. Is it possible to load my Windows 8 partition in a VirtualBox, or any other VM software? Or does it have to be created as a VM only?

I don't really need/want another installation of Windows at the moment, but I'd like to be able to use it from Ubuntu from time to time.

Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**VirtualBox Manual (9.9.1)**](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk), an actual disc drive can be used as opposed to a virtual disc file (such as VDI, VMDK or VHD) for VMs. It's referred to as a RAW disc.

VMWare is also capable of using an existing disc drive for a virtual machine. VMWare Fusion is intended for personal desktop use like this.

Edit: [**This tutorial**](http://www.theunixtips.com/virtualbox-use-raw-disk-to-load-windows-under-linux) looks like what you want.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Linux, so there's a lot of stuff in that tutorial that I cannot understand. Should this be a task for experienced users? Don't want to ruin anything :)

Comment: In Linux distros, `/dev` contains the devices available to the computer, whether they're actually connected or not. These devices must be mounted in order to read/write from/to them. Disc drives are typically `sd*`, where `*` is a letter. The first drive will be `sda`, and it's partitions `sda1`, `sda2`, etc. You can view the drives connected in the Disks utility in Ubuntu (search the Dash for "disk"). Once you know what the Windows disc is called, you should be able to add your user to the "disk" group, and create an MBR file for the disc. Please ask if you have any questions.